# Comma usage: In virtue of what[,] is any sequence of marks or noises meaningful?

Tags: commas

Compare: (1) In virtue of what is any sequence of marks or noises meaningful?
(2) In virtue of what, is any sequence of marks or noises meaningful?

Is this an appropriate use of a comma in (2)? I read this sentence is a book in which the comma isn't used, and I found my self confused about was going on in the sentence until I got till the end. 
To clarify, the author's meaning in the sentence (taken from a book on philosophy of language) is: what is it about a sequence of marks or noises that gives them meaning i.e. what is it about some marks/noises that make them words while others are just scribbles or din.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "In virtue of what".  However, if I did understand it, I would say: Omit the comma.

Comment: @aparente001 I've edited the question to clarify the intended meaning.

Comment: The sentence is poorly written regardless.  Punctuation won't save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed comma isn't appropriate, sorry.  But you are right, the sentence is a disaster.  If I were the editor of the book, I would not try to rescue the sentence with punctuation, but rewrite it.